# Flutter package pluto_grid: focus entire row (instead of a single cell)

Tags: flutter, pluto-grid

Flutter package pluto_grid offers various useful features.
However, I cannot find a way to customize it, so that the focus will be set to an entire row, rather than just one single cell.

Moving up and down (arrow keys) shall still move up and down one line, but left and right shall have no effect, as the entire row is focused already anyway.

I am aware of the functionality to (even multi) select rows.
Only, I would like to use both functionalities: focus (which is called activated internally) and selected, as my app needs to provide both functionalities.

Did I just not find how this could be configured?
Or is there maybe a work around to accomplish the desired behaviour?

I am currently using pluto_grid: ^8.0.0 and Flutter version 3.19.4.

I was browsing the documtation:
https://pluto.weblaze.dev/series/pluto-grid
https://weblaze.dev/pluto_grid/build/web/index.html

As Pluto Grid offers so many possibilities to configure the grid, I cannot believe, this was not possible.

I first thought, that some "group by" could maybe help, but meanwhile believe, that this cannot be used in my case.

If there is no out-of-the-box solution, I am sure, some workaround should do the trick.
Only I can't think of a clean solution at the moment, as I only started using PlutoGrid not so long ago and therefore am not 100% familiar with all its features yet.